# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx}{n^2+x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Does the following series converge uniformly on $x \in [-1,1]$? What about $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx}{n^2+x^2}
$$

My attempt:

Series converge pointwise to 
$$
f(x) = 0
$$
when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I want to ensure that
$$
\sup_{x \in E} \left| \frac{nx}{n^2+x^2} \right| \lt \epsilon
$$

by calculating derivative we obtain:
$$
f_n^{'}(x)=\frac{n(n^2-x^2)}{(n^2+x^2)^2} = 0 \iff x = \pm {n}
$$
We also know that $f_n$ increases on $(-\infty, -{n})$, decreases on $(-{n}, {n}$) and then increases to infinity. That means $-{n}$ is its local maximum. Plugging that into our function:
$$
f(-{n}) = \frac{-n^2}{2n^2} = -\frac{1}{2}
$$
I am not sure what can I conclude from here. Is that enough for $\mathbb{R}$ not having uniform convergence? Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Your use of terminology is confusing. A series converges if its partial sums converge; the partial sums of this series actually do not converge anywhere, save for $x = 0$.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that $f_n := \frac{nx}{n^2 + x^2}$ converges uniformly to some limit function $f$?

Comment: This series does not converge for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ except $x=0$

Comment: for any chosen $x\in[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$ the series behaves as the harmonic series, so it doesn't converge except for the case $x=0$ where the series is just zero

Comment: The series does not converge, thus also not uniformly, as it is asymptotically proportional to the harmonic series. Was there a series in the original task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the original task formulation: The series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx}{n^2+x^2}=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n^2+x^2}$$ does not converge at all, obviating the question about uniform convergence,
as for $n>|x|$ you get $$\frac{n}{n^2+x^2}>\frac1{2n}.$$ Thus the harmonic series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2n}$$ is a diverging minorant, proving divergence.

Answer (score 1):

I am choosing to interprete your question as the uniform convergence of $$f_n := \frac{nx}{n^2 + x^2},$$ because your question as stated does not line up with the rest of your argument.

Note that on the interval $[0,1]$, we have that $$f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{n^2 + x^2} \leq \frac{n}{n^2 + x^2} \leq \frac{n}{2n^2} \leq \frac{2}{n},$$ so we have uniform convergence.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks for pointing out my calculation error. I have edited the question.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My argument for the $[1, \infty)$ is wrong